# submit ID using multiple checkboxes in PHP HTML Mysql

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I am using multiple HTML checkboxes to submit student attendance. The checkbox once clicked submit '1' and if not checked, will submit '0'. I am able to submit '1' when checked but cant submit '0'. Below is my code:

```
<?php
    $subcheck = (isset($_POST['subcheck'])) ? 1 : 0;
    $date = date("Y/m/d");
    foreach ( $student as $attendance ) {
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>$attendance->id</td>";
                echo "<td>$attendance->name</td>";
                echo "<td>
                        $attendance->classroom_id
                      </td>";?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="date[]" value="<?php echo $date;?>" />

            <td><input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="<?php echo $attendance->id;?>"></td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="reason[]" ></td>

      <?php
            }
            ?>
<tr>  
      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit"></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might give you some ideas:

```
<?php
    $subcheck = (isset($_POST['subcheck'])) ? 1 : 0;
    $date = date("Y/m/d");

    $out = '<table id="tblAttendance"><thead><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Room</th><th>Status</th><th>Reason</th></thead><tbody>';
    foreach ( $student as $attendance ) {
        $out .= '<tr>';
        $out .=     '<td>' .$attendance->id. '<input type="hidden" name="studentID[]" value="' .$attendance->id. '"></td>';
        $out .=     '<td>' .$attendance->name. '<input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="' .$attendance->name. '"></td>';
        $out .=     '<td>' .$attendance->classroom_id. '<input type="hidden" name="classroomID[]" value="' .$attendance->classroom_id. '"></td>';
        $out .=     '<td><input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="yes"></td>';
        $out .=     '<td><input type="text" name="reason[]" ></td>';
        $out .= '</tr>';
    }
    $out .= '<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save" name="submit"></td></tr>';
    $out .= '</tbody></table>';
    $out .= '<input type="hidden" name="date" value="' .$date. '" />';
    echo $out;
?>
```

Since you are using a `type="submit"` button, I presume you have this inside a form construct?

Recall how checkboxes work in HTML forms: if the box is checked, the value received on the PHP side will be the `value="yes"` value. In other words, the variable `$_POST['status'][n]` will have the value `yes`.

HOWEVER, if the checkbox is not set, then `$_POST['status'][n]` will not be set.

Reference:

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

Comment: I think the question is not correctly understood. The code that you gave is doing the same thing without any change. I want value "0" to be sent when checkbox is not checked.